# node-phantom is not enabling javascript on web pages

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, phantomjs

I am using node-phantom to post items to a cart on a web site.  The problem is that when I use page.open to navigate to the shopping cart page (after already having added an item to the cart), I get an html response saying that I need to enable javascript in my browser in order to view the shopping cart page.  I've checked the settings.javascriptEnabled setting and found it to be set to 'true'.  At this point I am confused, why does the page think that phantomjs does not have javascript enabled?

Here is my code:

```
var phantom = require('node-phantom');

phantom.create(function (err, ph) {
    ph.createPage(function (err, page) {

        page.get('settings', function(err, oldSettings) {
            console.log('\r\n oldSettings:  ' + JSON.stringify(oldSettings));

            page.open('http://www.somesite.com/shoppingcart/default.cfm', function (err, status) {
                page.injectJs(jqueryPath, function (err) {
                    setTimeout(function() {     
                        page.evaluate(function (injectedSku) {
                            var localErr;
                            var skuInCart;
                            var checkoutLnkMsg;
                            var pageHTML;

                            try {              
                                pageHTML = $("html").html();

                                // Get 'SKUs' input element.
                                skuInCart = $('input[name="SKUs"]').val();

                                if (injectedSku === skuInCart) {
                                    var checkoutLnk = $('#cartAction_bottom a[alt="Checkout"');  

                                    checkoutLnk.on("click", function() {
                                        checkoutLnkMsg = '"' + checkoutLnk.href + '" link has been clicked';
                                    });

                                    checkoutLnk.click();            
                                } else {
                                    throw new Error('Product not in cart');
                                }
                            } catch (e) {
                              localErr = e;
                            }

                            return {
                                pageHTML: pageHTML,
                                err: localErr,
                                skuInCart: skuInCart,
                                checkoutLnkMsg: checkoutLnkMsg,
                                injectedSku: injectedSku
                            };

                        }, function (err, result) {
                            if (result.err) {
                                callback(err);
                                //return ph.exit();
                            }

                            fs.writeFileSync("./html_log.txt", result.pageHTML);
                            console.log('\r\n checkout - page.evaluate - injectedSku:  ' + result.injectedSku); 
                            console.log('\r\n checkout - page.evaluate - result.skuInCart:  ' + JSON.stringify(result.skuInCart));
                            console.log('\r\n checkout - page.evaluate - result.checkoutLnkMsg:  ' + result.checkoutLnkMsg);

                            callback(null);
                            //return ph.exit();
                        }, sku);
                    }, 1250);
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you paste the exact error you're getting please?

Comment: It's not really an error.  It's just an html response from the web site, with a message like "Please enable javascript in your browser in order to view this page correctly."

Comment: hmmm, have you tried my suggested solution below?

Comment: Yes, please see my comment next to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
page.injectJs()
```

with

```
page.includeJs()
```

**UPDATE**

```
var phantom = require('node-phantom');

phantom.create(function (err, ph) {
    ph.createPage(function (err, page) {

        page.get('settings', function(err, oldSettings) {
            //console.log('\r\n oldSettings:  ' + JSON.stringify(oldSettings));

            page.open('http://www.footlocker.com/shoppingcart/default.cfm?', function (err, status) {
                console.log(status);
                var sku = 234; // assign sku id here
                page.includeJs('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js', function (err) {
                    setTimeout(function() {     
                        page.evaluate(function (injectedSku) {
                            var localErr;
                            var skuInCart;
                            var checkoutLnkMsg;
                            var pageHTML;

                            try {              
                                pageHTML = $("html").html();

                                // Get 'SKUs' input element.
                                skuInCart = $('input[name="SKUs"]').val();

                                if (injectedSku === skuInCart) {
                                    var checkoutLnk = $('#cartAction_bottom a[alt="Checkout"');  

                                    checkoutLnk.on("click", function() {
                                        checkoutLnkMsg = '"' + checkoutLnk.href + '" link has been clicked';
                                    });

                                    checkoutLnk.click();            
                                } else {
                                    throw new Error('Product not in cart');
                                }
                            } catch (e) {
                              localErr = e;
                            }

                            return {
                                pageHTML: pageHTML,
                                err: localErr,
                                skuInCart: skuInCart,
                                checkoutLnkMsg: checkoutLnkMsg,
                                injectedSku: injectedSku
                            };

                        }, function (err, result) {
                            if (result.err) {
                                // callback(err);
                                //return ph.exit();
                            }

                            // fs.writeFileSync("./html_log.txt", result.pageHTML);
                            console.log('\r\n checkout - page.evaluate - injectedSku:  ' + result.injectedSku); 
                            console.log('\r\n checkout - page.evaluate - result.skuInCart:  ' + JSON.stringify(result.skuInCart));
                            console.log('\r\n checkout - page.evaluate - result.checkoutLnkMsg:  ' + result.checkoutLnkMsg);

                            // callback(null);
                            ph.exit();
                        }, sku);
                    }, 1250);
                });

            });
        });
    })
});
```

Comment: I've tried this, but now it just gets stuck on this line:  page.includeJs(jqueryPath, function (err) {...

Comment: I don't even get an err back.  The callback function just never gets called.

Comment: Instead of using `jqueryPath` serve your jQuery from a CDN using `'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'`. Also, right after `page.open()`, do `console.log('page opened', status)`. @bbeny

Comment: The 'status' after page.open() returns 'success', it always has.  I just didn't include it in the code example because I didn't think is was needed for the explanation of the problem.  Using the CDN to load jquery resolved the issue of the code getting stuck.  However, now I am back to the original problem where I get html back with a message "We're Sorry! You must have JavaScript enabled in your browser to experience all of the features of our site and to be able to place an order.  To continue, please enable JavaScript by changing the preferences in your browser, then fresh the page."

Comment: Have you tried programmatically enabling javascript on the page? `settings.javascriptEnabled = true;`?

Comment: Hmmm . . Have u had any luck since? Have you tried switching the website you're scraping.

Comment: No, no luck.  I will try to scrape a different site soon.

Comment: I've tried other sites and although I don't get the same "JavaScript not enabled" error, I do find that the shopping cart is always empty, even though in the previous step, I added an item to cart.  It seems like node-phantom is not able to persist cookies across page requests.  What ever the reason, the session is broken between the 'add to cart' page and the 'view cart' page.

Comment: hi @bbeny still haven't found a solution?

Comment: can I get access to this particular page?

Comment: The site is www.footlocker.com.  Just pick a shoe size and add the item to cart.  Then go to the cart page.  You'll see that the cart page will come up with nothing in the cart.  I used fiddler and noticed that the cookies don't match as opposed to when using a standard browser like Chrome.

Comment: Shame I've only got 45minutes left to try figure this out and get the bounty :(

Comment: @bbeny try the updated code, I wasn't getting any JS errors, I assigned a dummy `sku`, so you won't exactly get the right data. I also commented out some lines

Comment: if you extend the bounty Im sure I can come up with something @bbeny

Comment: I was never getting any javascript errors.  I was getting a page saying that javascript was not enabled.  If you look at the HTML of the downloaded cart page, you'll see that the page is not a valid cart page.  Also, if you use fiddler to examine the headers, you'll notice that the cookies (for example) are different from the cookies you would get if you visited the cart page using Chrome or IE.  I've tried this scenario with other sites and had similar problems.

Comment: One thing that I suspect is that Phantomjs is not executing the page's javascript.  For example, when I tried a similar example with finishline.com, I got results that suggested that the javascript on the page was disabled for some reason.  When clicking the 'Add to Cart' button, a javascript function would normally get called (in order to add the item to the cart) when using Chrome.  But, with Phantomjs, this function was not being called at all.

Comment: By the way, I tried you example, but the results were the same.  Were you actually able to see the correct sku listed in the cart page?

Comment: How do I extend the bounty on this question?